# PubNub ChatEngine "Converting circular structure to JSON" error after joining back to 1-1 chat using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chat, pubnub

I'm trying to wrap my head around this PubNub ChatEngine example using Angular for first time https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine-examples/tree/master/angular/simple

In demo when you click on user from the list new channel with random name is generated and user invited to it. So if you leave chat click on user again you connect to new channel.

I'm trying to do 1-1 chat rooms, that you could leave than join back, so changed channel name to be clicked user uuid. Now if I leave the channel, join back to it and try to send message it's not being shown in list, though it's being sent and user you are chatting with receives it.

In console I'm getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" when starting to type (as have chat engine typing indicator running) and after submit.

I guess that's something to do with removing chat from global scope using splice() method and after joining back new chat being added. It works in demo because there are getting new channel each time and removing it, but not if using same channel now. 
I tried to use splice() instead to see what happens. If I close chat and join back to it, it stays in DOM, and new one is added to scope, so have two same chat elements in DOM. If I type and send message on second one, it's not being displayed at it, but instead on first one that tried to close.
How could I get this working properly, can splice() be used in my case and I'm missing something else that is causing the error?

```
$scope.leave = (index) => {
   $scope.chat.leave();
   $scope.chats.splice(index, 1);
   //$scope.chats.slice(index, 1);
   //$scope.chats.splice( $scope.chats.indexOf($scope.chat), 1 );
}
```

````js
angular.module('chatApp', ['open-chat-framework'])
    .run(['$rootScope', 'ngChatEngine', function($rootScope, ngChatEngine) {

        $rootScope.ChatEngine = ChatEngineCore.create({
            publishKey: 'pub-c-d8599c43-cecf-42ba-a72f-aa3b24653c2b',
            subscribeKey: 'sub-c-6c6c021c-c4e2-11e7-9628-f616d8b03518'
        }, {
            debug: true,
            globalChannel: 'chat-engine-angular-simple'
        });

        // bind open chat framework angular plugin
        ngChatEngine.bind($rootScope.ChatEngine);

        // set a global array of chatrooms
        $rootScope.chats = [];

    }])
    .controller('Chat', function($scope) {

        $scope.chat.plugin(ChatEngineCore.plugin['chat-engine-typing-indicator']({
            timeout: 5000
        }));

        // every chat has a list of messages
        $scope.messages = [];

        // we store the id of the lastSender
        $scope.lastSender = null;

        // leave a chatroom and remove from global chat list
        $scope.leave = (index) => {
            $scope.chat.leave();
            $scope.chats.splice(index, 1);
        }

        // send a message using the messageDraft input
        $scope.sendMessage = () => {
            $scope.chat.emit('message', {
                text: $scope.messageDraft
            });
            $scope.messageDraft = '';
        }

        // when we get notified of a user typing
        $scope.chat.on('$typingIndicator.startTyping', (event) => {
            event.sender.isTyping = true;
        });

        // when we get notified a user stops typing
        $scope.chat.on('$typingIndicator.stopTyping', (event) => {
            event.sender.isTyping = false;
        });

        // function to add a message to messages array
        let addMessage = (payload, isHistory) => {

            // if this message was from a history call
            payload.isHistory = isHistory;

            // if the last message was sent from the same user
            payload.sameUser = $scope.messages.length > 0 && payload.sender.uuid == $scope.messages[$scope.messages.length - 1].sender.uuid;

            // if this message was sent by this client
            payload.isSelf = payload.sender.uuid == $scope.me.uuid;

            // add the message to the array
            $scope.messages.push(payload);

        }

        // if this chat receives a message that's not from this sessions
        $scope.chat.search({
            event: 'message'
        }).on('message', function(payload) {

            // render it in the DOM with a special class
            addMessage(payload, true);
        })

        // when this chat gets a message
        $scope.chat.on('message', function(payload) {
            // render it in the DOM
            addMessage(payload, false);
        });

    })
    .controller('OnlineUser', function($scope) {

        // create a new chat
        $scope.newChat = function(user) {

            // define a channel
            let chan = user.uuid;

            // create a new chat with that channel
            let newChat = new $scope.ChatEngine.Chat(chan);

            // we need to auth ourselves before we can invite others
            newChat.on('$.connected', () => {

                // this fires a private invite to the user
                newChat.invite(user);

                // add the chat to the list
                $scope.chats.push(newChat);

            });

        };

    })
    .controller('ChatAppController', function($scope) {


        // create a user for myself and store as ```me```
        $scope.ChatEngine.connect(new Date().getTime(), {}, 'auth-key');

        $scope.ChatEngine.on('$.ready', (data) => {

            $scope.me = data.me;

            $scope.me.plugin(ChatEngineCore.plugin['chat-engine-random-username']($scope.ChatEngine.global));

            $scope.ChatEngine.global.plugin(ChatEngineCore.plugin['chat-engine-online-user-search']());

            // when I get a private invit
            $scope.me.direct.on('$.invite', (payload) => {

                let chat = new $scope.ChatEngine.Chat(payload.data.channel);

                chat.onAny((a,b) => {
                    console.log(a)
                });

                // create a new chat and render it in DOM
                $scope.chats.push(chat);

            });

            // bind chat to updates
            $scope.chat = $scope.ChatEngine.global;

            // hide / show usernames based on input
            $scope.userSearch = {
                input: '',
                fire: () => {

                    // get a list of our matching users
                    let found = $scope.ChatEngine.global.onlineUserSearch.search($scope.userSearch.input);

                    // hide every user
                    for(let uuid in $scope.chat.users) {
                        $scope.chat.users[uuid].hideWhileSearch = true;
                    }

                    // show all found users
                    for(let i in found) {
                        $scope.chat.users[found[i].uuid].hideWhileSearch = false;
                    }

                }
            };

            $scope.userAdd = {
                input: '',
                users: $scope.userAdd,
                fire: () => {
                    if($scope.userAdd.input.length) {
                        $scope.userAdd.users = $scope.ChatEngine.global.onlineUserSearch.search($scope.userAdd.input);
                    } else {
                        $scope.userAdd.users = [];
                    }
                }
            };

        });

    });
````

```html
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ChatAppController">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="card">

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">ChatEngine</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Your are {{me.state.username}} with uuid {{me.uuid}}</p>
                </div>

                <ul id="online-list" class="list-group list-group-flush">

                  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(uuid, user) in chat.users" ng-hide="user.hideWhileSearch" ng-controller="OnlineUser">
                      <a href="#" ng-click="newChat(user)"> {{user.state.username}}</a>
                      <span class="show-typing" ng-show="user.isTyping">is typing...</span>
                  </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="card-block">

                    <form class="send-message" ng-submit="userSearch.fire()">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="usernameSearch" type="text" class="form-control message" placeholder="Search for Username" ng-change="userSearch.fire()" ng-model="userSearch.input">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <div id="chats" class="row" ng-repeat="chat in chats" ng-controller="Chat">

             <div class="chat col-xs-12">
                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            {{chat.channel}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                            <a href="#" ng-click="leave($index)" class="close">x</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush online-list-sub">

                      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(uuid, user) in chat.users" ng-hide="user.hideWhileSearch" ng-controller="OnlineUser">
                        {{user.state.username}}
                        <span class="show-typing" ng-show="user.isTyping">is typing...</span>
                      </li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="log">
                            <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="{'hide-username': message.sameUser, 'text-muted': message.isHistory, 'text-xs-right': !message.isSelf}">
                                <p class="text-muted username">{{message.sender.state.username}}</p>
                                <p>{{message.data.text}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="typing text-muted"></p>
                        <form class="send-message" ng-submit="sendMessage(chat)">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input ng-model="messageDraft" ng-change="chat.typingIndicator.startTyping()" type="text" class="form-control message" placeholder="Your Message...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="card-block">

                        <h6>Add a user to this chat</h6>

                        <fom ng-submit="userAdd.fire()">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="usernameSearch" type="text" class="form-control message" placeholder="Add User" ng-change="userAdd.fire()" ng-model="userAdd.input">
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush online-list-sub">

                          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(uuid, user) in userAdd.users" ng-controller="OnlineUser">
                              <a href="#" ng-click="invite(user, chat.channel)"> {{user.state.username}}</a>
                          </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Aivaras thank you for submitting this request.  We are looking into the issue.  JSON Serialization errors are common and sometimes easy to determine root cause.

Comment: Hi @Aivaras we've posted the question here: https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine/issues/330

Comment: @PubNub Thanks! It helped me to realise that wasn't using latest chat-engine version. All working now.

Comment: This has been added to the sprint to fix!  Updates to come in next sprint.  We are on 2-week sprint cycles.

Comment:  that is great news! Yes using latest version sometimes helps.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by upgrading to the latest ChatEngine version. As per the [ChatEngine github repo issue](https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine/issues/330):

> it's working correctly with chat-engine@0.9.5, I was using chat-engine@0.8.4